# HandShake Exception for Websocket

Tags: java, javascript, html, websocket, port

Trying to understand websocket.And strucked on a issue:
HTML page is having `onchange="ConnectSOMEServer(this)`

Now in function the code is just consturcting the URL

`var url = "ws://" + serverName +":" +portNumber;
  abc= new WebSocket(url); 
  SetSomething(abc);`

The error coming in console in Chrome is given below.

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://somethin-server:6767/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

-The Websocket class is in dom5.js

-Unable to understand where it is connection to server and where it is passing username(if at all).Where could i find the port.

-Other servers are also running for them the same code is working fine,only for one server it is showing above error on a particular port.If i do ping its showing all well.

I have searched on internet but it look little complex to me.Different type of implementations are there.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Q.Unable to understand where it is connection to server and where it is passing username(if at all).Where could i find the port.*

`Ans.Your html page is sending websocket request on a port.So the application should be having a TCP reciever up and running listening on the same port.`

*Q.Other servers are also running for them the same code is working fine,only for one server it is showing above error on a particular port.If i do ping its showing all well.*

`Ans.You can not guarantee here just check the ports the other applications TCP reciever might be listening on the same port which shows above is 6767`

Hope this helps.

Comment: You made my life easier.Thanks.Tested